# php set_time_limit, what's the exact behavior?

Tags: php, execution-time

I'm writing a piece of PHP code that at a certain point runs a `foreach` loop, and because I'm afraid that it takes too long, I added the statement `set_time_limit(20);` as the first line of the loop. (I'm assuming safe_mode and Suhosin patch not enabled.)

Now, I've been reading in http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php that

> When called, **set_time_limit()** restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

but I'm a little confused. In other words, if the loop runs, say, 10 times, and every loop will take 1 second to run, at the end of the 10th loop will the value of `max_execution_time` be increased to 20 * (10 - 1) = 180 seconds plus the initial `max_execution_time` value?

Comment: no every time its value rewrite to 20 if it inside in loop. also if its outside the loop then also value doesn't change if you didn't apply any code to modify it

Comment: set_time_limit(X) is basically you saying "I'm willing to wait for this for another X seconds" when those X seconds are up that's it. Doesn't matter what the limit was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from this [source](http://www.binarytides.com/php-set-time-limit/):

> The set_time_limit can be used to dynamically adjust the maximum execution time permitted to a script. It allows specifying the time in seconds and limits the script execution time to that many seconds.
>
> The set_time_limit function whenever called, effectively extends the script execution time by that many seconds. So if the script has already run for 15 seconds and set_time_limit(30) is called, then it would run for a total of 30+15 = 45 seconds. That's how its designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use set_time_limit() the countdown until the script will be killed/triggers max_execution_time error is reseted.

In your example, the script may run for 20 seconds after the last loop.